# How do I get my Crop Farm working?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you create a villager Crop Farm in Minecraft Bedrock Edition (Windows 10, version 1.12)?

When I spawn a Farmer villager on an empty field with a Composter and give him Seeds, he doesn't do a thing. But when I build this setup in Minecraft Java, everything works fine.

I provided a picture of my basic test setup with Seeds as proof that the villager cannot carry any more Seeds:

[image: Basic setup]

Comment: Always keep in mind that MCJava and MCBE are separate games that do not share any code.

Comment: You could try to plant wheat and then try it? I don't see what's wrong but that might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to actually plant the farm yourself. Then you want a fresh villager (child or cured zombie) to become your farmer. Give them 8 stacks of wheat seeds before letting them into your farm. Once they're fully grown let them in. This will let them pick up seeds for replanting and ensure they never get an inventory space to pick up wheat.

Currently potato farms don't work with villagers but this process can be done with beetroot as well. Carrots are a slightly different story.

Edit: also remember that as well as a composter to assign him a job, your villager will need a bed as well.